# React-Redux re-rendering after state changed

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to understand React+Redux. So, now I'm trying to fetch data from API, and faced with popular problem: when I change Redux state, it does not refresh my container component.

I read several questions here, most common problems are mutating state, and incorrect `connect` usage. I checked my code, everything looks fine. I suppose, that problem is in Reqct hook `useState`, in which I call my action generator. 
Code:

**Action generator**

```
export const requestAccounts = () => ({
  type: 'REQUEST_ACCOUNTS'
});

export const receivedAccounts = (data) => ({
  type: 'RECEIVED_ACCOUNTS',
  data
});

export const requestAccountsError = (errText) => ({
  type: 'RECEIVED_ACCOUNTS_ERROR',
  errText
});

export function getAccounts(clientRef = 1) {

  return async function (dispatch) {
    async function fetchData() {
      let res;
      try {
        res = await fetch("https://wstest.grant.ua/stubs/accnts.json", { //добавить парамтер "номер клиента"
            method: 'GET' // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        });
        if (res.ok) {
          let resJson = await res.json();
          dispatch(receivedAccounts(resJson.acn_list));
        }
        else {
          dispatch(requestAccountsError('Error during accounts request! Status '+res.status));
        }

      }
      catch (err) {
        dispatch(requestAccountsError(err.message));
      };   
    }
    dispatch(requestAccounts());
    await fetchData();
    /*I supposed that my problem depends on async loading, 
      so I tried to comment all above code and uncomment row below - also, 
      React did not re-render my component...*/
    //dispatch(requestAccountsError("ERROR_MESSAGEEEE"));
  }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    isFetching : false,
    isError : false,
    errorText : "",
    accounts : []
}

export function acnList(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "RECEIVED_ACCOUNTS":
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: false, 
            isError: false, 
            errorText: "", 
            accounts: action.acnList
          })
/*I tried to write return { errorText: "123" } - also no re-render.. So, problem is not in 
mutating previous state*/
      case "RECEIVED_ACCOUNTS_ERROR":          
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: false, 
            isError: true,
            errorText: "ERRTEXTTTT",
            accounts: []
        })
      case "REQUEST_ACCOUNTS":
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: true, 
            isError: false,
            errorText: "",
            accounts: []
        })
      default:
        return state
    }
}
```

**Container component**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import AcnListComponent from '../../MainMenuComponents/AcnListComponent'
import {getAccounts} from '../actions/actions'

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    acnList: state.acnList.accounts,
    isError: state.acnList.isError,
    isFetching: state.acnList.isFetching,
    errorText : state.acnList.errorText
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    getAccounts: () => {
      dispatch(getAccounts())
    }
  }
}

const AcnListContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(AcnListComponent)

export default AcnListContainer
```

And finally, part of my React-component code.

```
//imports

function AcnListComponent(props) {

  /*here I can see that props are changed sucessfully (according to state). But no re-render!*/
  console.log(props);
  const {t} = props;

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(props.isFetching);
  const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState(props.acnList);
  const [emptyMessage, setEmptyMessage] = useState(props.errorText);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(props.isError);

  useEffect(() => {
    if ((accounts.length === 0) && !isError) {
        props.getAccounts();
    }
  }, []); //I need to call this effect only once, when component renders
//renders
```

Looks really strange, like magic) 
Maybe, I do something wrong with `useEffect`, not with Redux? I need to make this request when my component renders, and re-render it with received data.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to copy props into state. just use them directly

Comment: Please take a loot at [this blog post](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/)

Comment: since you are copying props into state, you need to use ```useEffect``` to see if the props have chnaged and update them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `const [accounts, setAccounts] = useState(props.acnList);`

to `const accounts = props.acnList;`

Learn more on this [blog post](https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/).

You need to do it to all props that change.

**Edit**

Long story short:

This is a common mistake of copying the props into state.

Because props change over time and you need to update the state to reflect the props change (so many unecessary re-renders). The best is to use props directly.

Comment: as much as the blog post might be useful, it might not be there forever. Please copy the relevent parts into your answer.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I used state because of previous logic of this component (I did fetch directly in useEffect). Thans for great advice!)

Comment: @JuniusL. thanks for the advice, added a short explanation